# Cannot fetch JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, cors, fetch

I keep getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" when I try to fetch. What's wrong?
(i type in my browser: file:///C:/websites/test/a.html.)

a.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fetch API Demo</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

app.js:

```
async function getUsers() {
    let url = 'https://goldduo.com/users.json';

    try {
        let res = await fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'});
        const x=await res.json();
        console.log(x);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } 
}

getUsers();
```

I tried modifying and simplifying the JSON data. I also tried printing out res.text(), but it's blank.

Comment: yeah so, you are trying to fetch something that the provider of the resource has forbidden to be fetched by cors policies. You should not be surprised that setting "no-cors" won't magically circumvent the restrictions set by the resource provider

Comment: *"I also tried printing out res.text(), but it's blank."* That's intended and documented behavior: ["JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#no-cors)

Comment: @Yogi thanks. i tried your file and it worked. now i tried to make mine work by adding in my .htaccess file: <Files "*.json">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Files>, but it still wouldnt work?

Answer (score -1):

Your code would work fine if you serve it on your localhost, etc.
Your problem is that you are trying to fetch in a `file` that will result no response which cannot be consumed by `json()`

(There is also a extra backtick at the end of your html. Irrelevant to your issue though)

Comment: can you elaborate? what's the problem of fetching from a file? what cannot be consumed by json()?

Comment: Running something like 'file://c:/...'  doesn't invoke 'http' protocol. Fetch only supports http protocol. A browser with 'file://' in the address bar only attempts to display the contents. In case of HTML it renders them and parses the JavaScript to the extent of displaying the file content. For the fetch to work you need to have it on http. 'file' won't make any attempt to access network

Comment: after i added header access-control-allow-origin, it does display results from the source url?